# Query Optimization Increase due Table size Increase

Tags: sql, query-optimization

Query that used to take around 1 hour and is now taking 3 hours .
One issue is we found that the table DT_L_Item size has increased due to addition of Items ut still looking if there is something we can do.
Kindly help

Query:-

```
select  a12.CPY  ,
    a13.MANUFACTURER  MANUFACTURER,
    a11.COMPANY  COMPANY,
    a13.CATEGORY ,
    a11.BACKOFFICE ,
    a12.ABC  ,
    sum((Case when a11.ID_MONTH in (201701) then a11.VL_LANDED_COGS_TCY else NULL end))  WJXBFS1,
    sum((Case when a11.ID_MONTH in (201701) then a11.VL_NET_SALES_TCY else NULL end))  WJXBFS2,
(Case when max((Case when a11.ID_MONTH in (201701) then 1 else 0 end)) = 1 then count(distinct (Case when a11.ID_MONTH in (201701, 201702, 201703, 201704, 201705, 201706) then a11.ID_MONTH else NULL end)) else NULL end)  WJXBFS3,
sum((Case when a11.ID_MONTH in (201701) then a11.VL_GLOBAL_COGS_TCY else NULL end))  WJXBFS4,
sum((Case when a11.ID_MONTH in (201701) then a11.VL_SPECIAL_TAX_TCY else NULL end))  WJXBFS5,
sum((Case when a11.ID_MONTH in (201801) then a11.VL_LANDED_COGS_TCY else NULL end))  WJXBFS6,
(Case when max((Case when a11.ID_MONTH in (201801) then 1 else 0 end)) = 1 then count(distinct (Case when a11.ID_MONTH in (201801, 201802, 201803, 201804, 201805, 201806) then a11.ID_MONTH else NULL end)) else NULL end)  WJXBFS7,
sum((Case when a11.ID_MONTH in (201801) then a11.VL_NET_SALES_TCY else NULL end))  AYP_Sales_last_3_Months,
sum((Case when a11.ID_MONTH in (201801) then a11.VL_SPECIAL_TAX_TCY else NULL end))  WJXBFS8,
sum((Case when a11.ID_MONTH in (201801) then a11.VL_GLOBAL_COGS_TCY else NULL end))  WJXBFS9
from    FV_SALES    a11
join    DT_L_Item   a12
  on    (a11.COMPANY = a12.COMPANY and 
a11.ITEM = a12.ITEM)
join    DT_G_Item   a13
  on    (a11.G_ITEM = a13.ITEM)
join    LV_COMPANY  a14
  on    (a11.COMPANY = D_COMPANY)
where   (a11.ID_COMPANY in (ABC)
 and (a11.MONTH in (201701)
 or a11.MONTH in (201801)))
group by    a12.CPY  ,
    a13.MANUFACTURER  MANUFACTURER,
    a11.COMPANY  COMPANY,
    a13.CATEGORY ,
    a11.BACKOFFICE ,
    a12.ABC
```

Comment: What are the table's unique keys?

Comment: What DBMS are you asking this for? MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL, ...?